# How to restore sound and microphone configuration Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I was recently gifted a macbook with Ubuntu 20.04. In the beginning, the speakers were not working, but headphones would, and the microphone was functional. I attempted the solutions found online and ended up losing both the microphone and the ability to hear through headphones (i.e. no sound at all not just no built-in speakers) after a reboot.

Is there some list of original drivers or some software that can help me get my system to full sound and microphone use?

Comment: Short answer: no. Just about every driver for most MacBooks had to be reverse-engineered or hacked together to provide the functionality that exists. That said, if you can [edit] your question to include the model of the MacBook, it may be possible to offer a solution that will restore your microphone and headphones.

Comment: Have you tried to reverse your "attempted solution"?